# Overlay images and customize x,y position in the watchOS storyboard

Tags: swift, watchos-2, xcode-storyboard

I want to duplicate this design mockup and use it in production.

iOS has Z-hierarchy for arranging on Z axis, but it's greyed out in watchOS. I want to create an overlay of a profile avatar like this Instagram prototype where only half of the avatar is over the main image.

Naturally I would like all profile images from the server to be placed in the small round imagview which goes on top of the photos in the stream.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. It takes some tinkering. The [group layout overlap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacegroup) option in the Attribute Inspector works as advertised. My case was unique because I not only wanted an overlay but I also wanted only half of the avatar to overlap as in the Instagram prototype.

1. Set the group layout overlap attribute to the **root group** since that has to be done or this to work.
2. Next apply the overlap attribute to the **avatar group** since it is the group we want to overlap on top of the cat group.
3. Use **bottom insets** on the **cat group** to push the avatar down. Adjust accordingly. Naturally, if you want a 50% overhang the bottom inset value should be half of the avatar height.
4. The **cat group** does **not** need the overlap attribute.
5. The circular avatar is not a circular Photoshop element. I simply adjusted the radius of the **avatar group** to make it round.

Note: You'll get a warning from Xcode when using Overlap.

> Interface.storyboard: notice: Discouraged Configuration: Overlap layout falls back to vertical when used before watchOS 4.0

[image]

[image]
[image]